# ExtJS hiding href value

Tags: javascript, php, extjs

I'm new to extJS and I've noticed something, it might be a stupid question but here it is

```
var cntMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    items: [{
        text:"Articles",
        iconCls: 'bmenu',
        icon:'images/menu-images/s.gif',
        handler: onItemClick,
        data:'manage-post.php'
    }]
);
```

generates the following code

```
<a class="x-menu-item-link" href="#" hidefocus="true" unselectable="on" id="ext-gen1227">
    <img src="images/menu-images/s.gif" class="x-menu-item-icon bmenu" id="ext-gen1228">
    <span class="x-menu-item-text" id="ext-gen1229">Articles</span>
</a>
```

My question is how is the href showing "#" ? Clicking on the link works as it would if I clicked on an normal php link.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean usual html-link? Your button is not a link. You have to add code in your handler function and make navigate by javascript manner:

```
onItemClick: function(button, event, opts){
    document.location.href ='your link'; // manage-post.php?
}
```

If I understood you correctly.
Or shorter:

```
var cntMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    items: [{
        text:"Articles",
        iconCls: 'bmenu',
        icon:'images/menu-images/s.gif',
        handler: function(button, event, opts){
            document.location.href ='your link'; // manage-post.php?
        },
        data:'manage-post.php'
    }]
);
```